Create CurrencyType
I have activated the multicurrency option in my organization. I am trying to add all the exchange rates that my client has, but they use very old currencies and from small countries. When I open the currency type drop-down menu, I don't see these currencies. My question is, can values ​​be added to this list?

Thank you in advance.

I suggest that create a case with Salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/s/case-submission

Do you have an example?
